# Does ubuntu support Toshiba Satellite C55-B5101?

Tags: toshiba-satellite

I would like to know if my laptop is supported to run Ubuntu and its many flavours and what would be the best flavour.

 I have a `4 GB` ram DDR3 and `500 GB` with dual core Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU `N2840@2`,`16Ghz` base speed and with an Intel turbo boost speed of `2.57GHZ`.

Comment: You can download a Live CD or Live USB distribution, burn it to CD/USB, boot it and try Ubuntu without intstalling it. That's the only way to see if Ubuntu "works" for you.

Comment: That's exactly the same laptop I have, and it works without problems, so the answer is yes :)

Comment: really yay I'm actually downloading the ISO at the moment but how is the gaming ?

Comment: I don't play games, so can't say.

Comment: oh ok cool well thanks anyway I actually going to Ubuntu because i'm tired of windows and I wanna learn some programming skills :)

Comment: @JakeMatthews Start with Python if you're going to learn programming. It's much easier to understand for beginners, and is very versatile.